# Can I use one variable for different containers (List, Set, Map)?

Tags: java, collections

It is necessary to change a container type:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyContainers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("title1");
        list.add("title2");
        System.out.println(list.indexOf("title1"));

        // change container type
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
    }
}
```

But it will be better to use only one variable. I wrote such code but there was a restriction (see comment):

```
import java.util.*;


public class MyContainers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("title1");
        list.add("title1");

        System.out.println(list);

        // Can't call indexOf because there are no such method in inteface Collection
        //System.out.println(list.indexOf("title1")); 

        // change container type
        list = new HashSet<String>(list);
        System.out.println(list);   

    }
}
```

Please, help me with such questions:

1. Is it possible to use one variable for different containers and use full set of containers methods?
2. Is it possible to convert List to `Map`?
   Please, show a code examples.

Comment: You can't have it both ways!  If you want to use a common type for different collections, you'll have to accept that you won't be able to call methods that don't exist for some of those collections (e.g. `indexOf` doesn't make sense for `Set`).

Comment: [1] if you define the method behavior for each class and [2] if you define how do you expect to convert it (odd is key and even is value?). You see, you can have a "one interface rule them all", but you have to specify what each method mean for each structure first.

Comment: How is it "better" to use only one variable.  It's actually more confusing since it's harder to reason about your code. "Which set am I looking at?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If some method doesn't exist in one *interface*, it doesn't exist for a reason. Don't try to have a workaround in order to have it, that'll usually lead to troubles. For example, it doesn't make any sense to have `indexOf` method for the [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) *interface*.

However, it can be useful sometimes to construct a new object of different type from an existing one, for example, if you have an `ArrayList` and you don't want to have duplicates, it does make sense to convert it to `HashSet`.

You should pick the best *interface* that suits your needs, if you don't find any, you can always implement your own class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, is it good?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyContainers {

    static Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        collection.add("title1");
        collection.add("title1");

        System.out.println(collection); // [title1, title1]
        useIndexOf();
        System.out.println(collection); // [title1, title1]
        deleteDublication();
        System.out.println(collection); // [title1]
    }

    public static void useIndexOf()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(collection);
        System.out.println(list.indexOf("title1")); // 0
        // Change container type back to universal
        collection = list;
    }

    public static void deleteDublication() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(collection);
        collection = set;
    }

}
```